# Determine if 3D point is inside 2D Circle

Tags: math, geometry, raytracing

I wish to determine if a Point P(x,y,z) is inside a 2D circle in 3D space defined by its center C (cx, cy, cz), radius R, and normal to the plane the circle lies on N.

I know that a point P lying on a 2D circle in 3D space is defined by:

P = R*cos(t)***U*** + Rsin(t)*( **N** x **U** ) + C

where **U** is a unit vector from the center of the circle to any point on the circle. But given a point Q, how do I know if Q is on or inside the circle? What is the appropriate parameter `t` to choose? And which coordinates do I compare the point Q to see if they are within the circle?

Thanks.

Comment: Care to clarify your notation? What's this **noise** about? Looks like it could be the magnitude of a vector, but it encourages others to provide useful answers when your question is clearly presented.

Comment: I tried to bold them but they wouldn't bold....? the **U** is a bold vector, indicating a vector. Same for **N**. EDIT: I bolded the letters by taking them out of the "code" section

Comment: Did you try looking up info on 3d mouse picking?

Comment: @HyperCas: I did. I'm not sure it's applicable. The problem seems to be much simpler...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Project P onto the plane containing the circle, call that P'.  P will be in the circle if and only if |P - P'| = 0 and |P' - C| < R.

Comment: and if I wish to include the boundary of the point in my check, do I check |P-C|<=R and |P-P'|=0?

Comment: Presumably all your coordinates are floating-point numbers, which means you should be careful when doing things like "|P - P'| = 0". It will rarely come out to EXACTLY zero, so you can do something like "|P - P'| < e" where e is some very very small number.

Comment: @Myx, Yes, and the point that MatrixFrog makes is also very salient for actual implementation. Also, tloflin's thought of checking <P-C, N> = 0 (or within some suitably small range about 0) instead is probably a better choice (easier to compute) than my suggestion of projecting P onto the nearest point P' in the plane containing the circle.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. For me, I already had a Project function implemented so it didn't matter to me which one I used (Project or Dot product with Normal).

Comment: We need latex, this answer would so much better with latex.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this by breaking it into two parts:

1. Find out if the point is on the same plane as the circle (ie. see if the dot product of the vector going from the center to the point and the normal is zero)
2. Find out if it's inside the sphere containing the circle (ie. see if the distance from the center to the point is smaller than the radius).